# how to add comment to SVG file written by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

Given an example plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [2,4,6])
plt.savefig('simple.plot.svg')
```

how can I write a comment into that SVG file?

for example, I would like to write that the SVG file was written by `simple.plot.py`

I have seen there may be a way to add comments: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_svg_api.html I am not a python or matplotlib expert, however, and I don't know how I could implement that.

I was hoping that something like `plt.savefig('simple.plot.svg', comment = "written by simple.plot.py")` would be available, but alas, this functionality doesn't seem to exist: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

but I have no idea how I could implement that into a simple script like I have above, how can I do so?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation only show the `comment` attribute for the `XMLWriter`?

Comment: @jared SVG is an XML-based markup language, so I figure they would be the same thing, or SVG would depend on XML libraries

Comment: @Raymond the comment will be shown inside the SVG file, and not visible in the plot

Comment: Try something like `plt.savefig('simple.plot.svg', metadata={'Creator': 'simple.plot.py'})`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher excellent! That works! if you write down your answer as an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.savefig` accepts an argument `metadata` which should be a dictionary with keys being strings and values dependent on the desired output format.

For SVG, the keys and values should follow the Dublin Core standard.

Here, the key should be `'Creator'` and the value the name of the program as string:

```
plt.savefig('simple.plot.svg', metadata={'Creator': 'simple.plot.py'})
```